# Is there a generic way to implement if status box true then turn row to green on Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of specifying each checkbox name, and input parameters, is there a generic way to implement a row color change based on a checkbox status?

Say I have a function that checks the status of a checkbox

```
Function Green(box1 As String, row as String)
If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(box1).Value = xlOn Then
   Range(row).Interior.ColorIndex  = 4
Else
   Range(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
End Function

Sub Checkbox1_click()
Application.Run "Green", "Check Box 1", "1:1"
End Sub
```

The Problem with this is that I need to define these 3 arguments all the time, and also lets say I have to shift a set of items down, the codes won't shift along

Any Idea how to build a more generic way to implement a checkbox that changes row color without arguments indicating what row it's in?

Comment: Off subject, there is a missing `End If`

Comment: It's kind of difficult to figure out what you're really trying to account for. Each Checkbox on your sheet has its own event handler. What's wrong with that approach? What do you mean "I have to shift a set of items down"?  What's a "set of items"? Why does it need to shift?

Comment: @DavidZemens Say you need to add a new row in between, and it requires you to shift all the rows under it down, you'd need to reprogram all the rows checkboxes if they move down as well

Comment: You could use named ranges.  Let say you name cell `A1` range "RefRange", you could call `Application.Run "Green", "Check Box 1", Me.Range("RefRange").EntireRow.Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that you have something like 1 check box for each row in the worksheet, or something like that, and that each checkbox should always correspond to the row that it's *in*.

Instead of hard-coding the Row argument like `"1:1"` in your example, do this instead:

```
Sub Checkbox1_click()
    Application.Run "Green", "Check Box 1", _
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").TopLeftCell.Row
End Sub
Sub Checkbox2_click()
    Application.Run "Green", "Check Box 2", _
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 2").TopLeftCell.Row
End Sub    

Function Green(box1 As String, row as Long)
If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(box1).Value = xlOn Then
   Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex  = 4
Else
   Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
End Function
```

As long as you've configured the checkboxes to move with the cells, then this should work no matter what you do in terms of inserting rows/etc.

**UPDATE FROM COMMENTS**

Sometimes the checkbox *appears* to be in one row but the `.TopLeftCell` property is a different row. This is because the `.TopLeftCell` property is the top left corner of the checkbox control's frame, not just the physical "checkbox" itself. Selecting the checkbox in design mode can show that the `.TopLeftCell` may be in Row 1 even though the checkbox appears to be in Row 2.  You can also verify this by debugging:

[image]

Comment: **This assumes that you have something like 1 check box for each row in the worksheet, or something like that, and that each checkbox should always correspond to the row that it's in**  If your checkboxes are not **in** the row that you want them to color, then you'll need to modify the code accordingly, e.g., `Rows(row + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4` would color the row **beneath** the checkbox is located.

Comment: It's odd because they actually are on the same row as designated. But that's one way around it, thanks!

Comment: @echad well it all depends on what Excel is reading as the checkbox's `.TopLeftCell` address. Glad this resolved your question, I've also updated the answer to clarify based on your most recent comment.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First you create a named range on cell `A1` like this:

[image]

Then you modify your code to use the address of the entire row of this named range rather than hard-coding it:

```
Sub Checkbox1_click()
    Application.Run "Green", _
                    "Check Box 1", _
                    Me.Range("RefRange").EntireRow.Address
End Sub
```

The address from `Me.Range("RefRange").EntireRow.Address` will give you `"$1:$1"` at first, then if you insert a row before that range the address will show `"$2:$2"`.